# Multiple conversation with different users in AIML

Tags: chat, chatbot, aiml

So what i want to do is to make a conversation between bot and a person, but the bot in the end must have at least 3 conversation between different persons. I was looking a lot for this but i cannot find anything that works.

Can somebody help me explaining how can i make multiple conversations  between a bot and multiple users?

Comment: Surely, all chatbots have multiple conversations with different people? A chatbot that could only talk to one person wouldn't be much use and a site like www.pandorabots.com will allow you to create a chatbot. The one I created is at www.mitsuku.com and often has hundreds of users at once talking to it.

If this doesn't help, please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Bots developed in AIML aren't totally stateless as they can save per-user information while interacting with a user.

Your bot as a whole can interact with N number of users as there are no such limitations to AIML bots.

If you are saving variables using `Set` tag

```
<set name = "variable-name"> variable-value </set>
```

```
<category>
  <pattern>I AM *</pattern>
  <template>
     Hi there <set name="name"> <star/>!</set>
  </template>  
</category>
```

Then it maybe stored for that particular user or as a global variable depending on the implementation of AIML specification you are using.

I am not much of an AIML expert but I do have used SIML for bot development.

In **SIML** however per-user information or variables are stored separately in the following fashion.

```
<Model>
 <Pattern>WHAT IS MY NAME</Pattern>
 <Response>Your name is <User Get="name"/></Response>
</Model>
```